Normalize XML via fasterxml jackson
I have a list of objects that I can serialize using FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml. All of these objects reference other objects that also get serialized. So far so good.
But many of my objects in the list reference the same other object, and currently that other object gets serialized for every reference.
Instead I'd like to serialize them all only once, then reference them.
How can I setup FasterXML to once serialize Other as full object and once as reference only? The solution must be capable of serializing and deserializing the concept.
Here is a reproducible example. The following code
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Other {
    private String name;
    
    public Other(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    
}

class ListObject {
    private String name;
    private Other other;
    
    public ListObject(String name, Other other) {
        this.name = name;
        this.other = other;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Other getOther() {
        return other;
    }

    public void setOther(Other other) {
        this.other = other;
    }
    
}

public class XMLTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Other commonOther = new Other("common");

        List<ListObject> l = new ArrayList();
        l.add(new ListObject("One", commonOther));
        l.add(new ListObject("two", commonOther));
        
        XmlMapper mapper = XmlMapper.builder()
                .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT)
                .build();
        mapper.writeValue(System.out, l);
    }
}

yields this output:
<ArrayList>
  <item>
    <name>One</name>
    <other>
      <name>common</name>
    </other>
  </item>
  <item>
    <name>two</name>
    <other>
      <name>common</name>
    </other>
  </item>
</ArrayList>

Instead my idea would be to add the list of Others, then reference these entries from the ListObjects like so:
<Data>
    <Others>
      <other>
        <name>common</name>
      </other>
    </Others>
    <ArrayList>
      <item>
        <name>One</name>
        <other ref="common"/>
      </item>
      <item>
        <name>two</name>
        <other ref="common"/>
      </item>
    </ArrayList>
</Data>


I could be wrong, but avoiding cyclical references is meant to be via the @JsonIdentityInfo annotation. You might wish to look at that. https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-docs/wiki/Presentation-Jackson-2.0

@majixin An interesting read, although I do not have cyclic references. I just wanted to remove duplicated data.

Sorry if I misunderstood, but I think the outcome is the same. Due to this from that link: "First instance of an Object is serialized completely (including Object Id); further references are serialized using Object Id itself", it should fit/match your request of "to once serialize Other as full object and once as reference only". Apologies again, if there's a subtlety I've misunderstood.
